# entry / asset url integrity check

Tags: assets, plugins, entry, url, delete

Is there any mechanism in Craft (or a plugin) which protects entries or assets from being deleted, if they are used in an asset / entry field used in an entrytype, global, ...?

Or is there a way to show how many relations an asset or an entry has? (I know some CMSs which show you the amount of "inbound" links to the assets and pages).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just saw this. Consider this plug-in:
https://github.com/born05/craft-assetusage

Comment: Thanks for this!